# Up-Vote Etiquette

Tags: discussion

My daughter and I started using SE recently. My daughter is starting to learn *Mathematica*, and both of us are very interested in math, science, and coding. We have been voting up some of each other's answers and I was wondering if that was okay.

Comment: [A meta.SE thread](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/126829) you might want to look into. FWIW: vote her answers because they are sensible and interesting, not because they were written by your daughter.

Comment: @J.M. Very helpful link and practical advice. We are at the same IP address so that may be interpreted as sockpuppetry ... We'll just avoid voting on each others stuff.